# Data binding in Polymer - function is being removed from bound object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm encountering an issue binding an object that contains a function from angular to Polymer 1.0. The function is not being passed through into the target object in the custom element. Here is a simplified code sample:

The custom element has a single property named myprop:

```
<script>    
    Polymer({
        is: 'my-custom-element',
        properties: {
            myprop: Object
        },
        attached: function () {
            var x = this.myprop.x;       //this is ok
            this.myprop.myfunc();        //myfunc is not defined!   

        }
    });

</script>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <my-custom-element myprop="{{myobject}}"></my-custom-element>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the angular controller:

```
<script>
    angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {    
        $scope.myobject= {
          x: 4,
          myfunc: function() {
             //function body
          } 
        }    
    });    
</script>
```

Why isn't the function available in the custom element?

Comment: If {{myobject}} returns an object this should works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented here: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/3e96425bf0e0ba49b5f1f2fd2b6008e45a206692/PRIMER.md#attribute-deserialization

... objects passed into polymer elements are being passed through `JSON.stringify` and then `JSON.parse` (depending on variable type).

Functions will be completely stripped out by JSON.stringify - just checkout out this sample...

```
console.log( JSON.stringify({x:123,y:function(){ return 123; }}) );
// outputs: {"x":123}
```

I believe this is the offending line in source...

https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/3b0d10b4da804703d493da7bd0b5c22fc6f7b173/src/micro/attributes.html#L232

... and comments nearby suggest possibility to change this behavior...

> Users may override this method on Polymer element prototypes to provide serialization for custom types

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm marking this as the answer. Though I am a little confused why the code sample from horacioibrahim suggests that the function gets preserved when angular is taken out of the equation.

Comment: @StevenSmith I think horacioibrahim's sample works because it is not being passed in from outside via attribute, but rather it is being directly bound to internal property, which can be set to anything javascript can handle.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call Angular function like you write `this.myprop.myfunc();` 
I can't explain why this is so, but if you want call Angular function  from Polymer you can use `this.fire('nameEvent')` and in Angular controller or run module add event listener like

```
document.addEventListener('nameEvent', function() {
//function body  
})
```

I hope that help you. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I'm not simulating with Angular but I think that {{myobject}} can have a problem. Only with Polymer works fine. 
Basically I copied your code in the my-element and created my-element-two where I import the it. The result is "My name" printed in the lifecycle `attached`.

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="my-element">
<script>    
    Polymer({
        is: 'my-element',
        properties: {
            myprop: Object,
        },
        attached: function () {
            var x = this.myprop.x;       //this is ok
            this.myprop.myfunc();        //myfunc is not defined!   
        }
    });
</script>
</dom-module>

<dom-module id="my-element-two">
<template>
    <my-element myprop="{{myobject}}"></my-element>
</template>

<script>    
    Polymer({
        is: 'my-element-two',
        properties: {
            myobject: {
                type: Object,
                value: {
                    x: 4,
                    myfunc: function() {
                        console.log("My name");
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    });

</script>
</dom-module>

<!-- results is print "My name" in the console. -->
<my-element-two></my-element-two>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and for taking the time to produce this sample.