# Uncaught TypeError: this.hoodie.account.signUp is not a function

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, hoodie

Why does my element throw the following error when it's served through an iron-component-page element (in a Polymer Seed Element demo), but not when served normally through my app?

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.hoodie.account.signUp is not a function
```

The demo is published at http://timblack1.github.io/hoodie-accountbar/components/hoodie-accountbar/.

`this.hoodie` should be created by hoodie.js, which does load according to Dev Tools' Network tab.  But the `this.hoodie` object doesn't contain as many methods and attributes as it should, including the `.account.signUp()` method.  `this.hoodie.account` exists, but only as an empty object.

I'm loading hoodie.js via a `<script>` tag in the `hoodie-service` element, which is loaded by `hoodie-accountbar`. Does the iron-component-page element do anything funny when it loads  tags in a demo element?  Or does hydrolysis?

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31265782/data-binding-in-polymer-function-is-being-removed-from-bound-object

Comment: Thank you, @scarygami.  Now I see that for some reason re-publishing hoodie-service.hoodie as a property named hoodie-accountbar.hoodie stripped out all of the hoodie object's methods, though it appears that publishing hoodie from hoodie-service did not have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@scarygami's comment pointed the way to the fix.  The problem is that published properties are run through `JSON.stringify()`, which strips out any methods defined on those published property objects.  So I fixed this error by no longer making the `hoodie` property be a published property on the `hoodie-accountbar` element.  The fix is at https://github.com/timblack1/hoodie-accountbar/commit/db8d3071e4ad53a71b3d0e834075f00967c2e4a4.